# How to navigate to new url after login to instagram using c#

Tags: c#, authentication, instagram

hi i'm trying to build an app that allow to login to instagram using c#

when i run my application and logged in , i need to be redirected to fixed page 
without any reaction from me

here's my code  :

```
  {
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HtmlDocument doc = web.Document;
        HtmlElement username = doc.GetElementById("id_username");
        HtmlElement password = doc.GetElementById("id_password");

        username.SetAttribute("value", "test");
        password.SetAttribute("value", "test");

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (HtmlElement elm in web.Document.All)
            if (elm.GetAttribute("value") == "Log in")
            {
                sb.Append(elm.InnerHtml);

                Thread.Sleep(3000);
                elm.InvokeMember("click");
                web.Navigate(@"https://instagram.com/accounts/edit/"); // it navigate me but required to login again 


            }



    }

    private void web_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (web.Document.Url.AbsoluteUri.Equals(@"https://instagram.com"))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("logged in");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep session cookies. Better to use some component that allow you to connect to instagram, like: https://www.nuget.org/packages/InstaSharp/

Comment: can u provide a suggestion of how to use cookie with webBrowser component in c# @Artur Malendowicz